# Reserved character codes in Unicode

Tags: unicode, character, reserved

Why Unicode has several reserved character codes?
See the Unicode for two languages- [Kannada](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0C80.pdf) and [Tamil](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0B80.pdf). 
Both language are very old and I think there is no chance to get new characters to these languages.
EDIT: Then why are they wasting some character codes by making it reserved character codes?
Why are they not placing the reserved character codes at the end of each language character set?

Comment: I understand being curious, but is there another reason you're asking?

Comment: Please explain: do you mean to ask why there are unassigned slots within those blocks?

Comment: @Oded I think you are misunderstanding his question, because your question is a *non sequitur*.  I don’t know for sure it’s even offtopic.

Comment: @MarkRansom I thought there may have some programmatic reason behind it.

Comment: @Oded Sorry, The question was bit confusing. I made it more clear.

Comment: @habeebperwad Ok, answered below. The short story is the they usually reserve an entire 4, 8, or 16 element row for characters of the same flavor, like a row for letters, or one for marks, or one for punctuation. So if they don’t have enough for the entire row, they leave the remainer unused.  Think of padding in C structures where you get aligned on word boundaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with how the Unicode consortium doles out its allocated blocks, scripts, and code points. For example, in `Block=Tamil`, the start of it runs this way:

```
$ unichars '\p{Block=Tamil}' | head -20
U+00B82 ‭ ◌ஂ  GC=Mn SC=Tamil        TAMIL SIGN ANUSVARA
U+00B83 ‭ ஃ  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL SIGN VISARGA
U+00B85 ‭ அ  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER A
U+00B86 ‭ ஆ  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER AA
U+00B87 ‭ இ  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER I
U+00B88 ‭ ஈ  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER II
U+00B89 ‭ உ  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER U
U+00B8A ‭ ஊ  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER UU
U+00B8E ‭ எ  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER E
U+00B8F ‭ ஏ  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER EE
U+00B90 ‭ ஐ  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER AI
U+00B92 ‭ ஒ  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER O
U+00B93 ‭ ஓ  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER OO
U+00B94 ‭ ஔ  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER AU
U+00B95 ‭ க  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER KA
U+00B99 ‭ ங  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER NGA
U+00B9A ‭ ச  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER CA
U+00B9C ‭ ஜ  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER JA
U+00B9E ‭ ஞ  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER NYA
U+00B9F ‭ ட  GC=Lo SC=Tamil        TAMIL LETTER TTA
```

They tend to reserve contiguous rows of 4, 8, or 16 code points to all the same “kind” of character.  Yes, there are gaps there, but it’s like how in the filesystem, once you allocate a sector (or block if you don’t have separate sectors within a block) to one file, even if that file doesn’t use everything in its (final) sector, you don’t go giving away those unused byte to some other process.  Things tend to get padded to block boundaries anyway.

It’s not like we’re at any risk of running out of codes.

Here is the beginning of the allocated area starts with “Signs”, as shown by the first assigned code points in that block. The gap may represent a change from one kind of character to another.  If you check out the first five code points in the block for their properties, you see that those unassigned code points still have the right block property:

```
$ uniprops -a U+00B80 U+00B81 U+00B82 U+00B83 U+00B84 U+00B85
U+0B80 ‹U+0B80› \N{U+0B80}
    \pC \p{Cn}
    All Any InTamil C Other Cn Unassigned Zzzz Unknown
    Age=Unassigned Bidi_Class=L Bidi_Class=Left_To_Right BC=L Block=Tamil Canonical_Combining_Class=0 Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered
       CCC=NR Canonical_Combining_Class=NR Decomposition_Type=None DT=None East_Asian_Width=Neutral Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Other GCB=XX
       Grapheme_Cluster_Break=XX Hangul_Syllable_Type=NA Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable HST=NA Joining_Group=No_Joining_Group
       JG=NoJoiningGroup Joining_Type=Non_Joining JT=U Joining_Type=U Line_Break=Unknown LB=XX Line_Break=XX Numeric_Type=None NT=None
       Numeric_Value=NaN NV=NaN Present_In=Unassigned IN=Unassigned Script=Unknown SC=Zzzz Script=Zzzz Sentence_Break=Other SB=XX
       Sentence_Break=XX Word_Break=Other WB=XX Word_Break=XX
U+0B81 ‹U+0B81› \N{U+0B81}
    \pC \p{Cn}
    All Any InTamil C Other Cn Unassigned Zzzz Unknown
    Age=Unassigned Bidi_Class=L Bidi_Class=Left_To_Right BC=L Block=Tamil Canonical_Combining_Class=0 Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered
       CCC=NR Canonical_Combining_Class=NR Decomposition_Type=None DT=None East_Asian_Width=Neutral Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Other GCB=XX
       Grapheme_Cluster_Break=XX Hangul_Syllable_Type=NA Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable HST=NA Joining_Group=No_Joining_Group
       JG=NoJoiningGroup Joining_Type=Non_Joining JT=U Joining_Type=U Line_Break=Unknown LB=XX Line_Break=XX Numeric_Type=None NT=None
       Numeric_Value=NaN NV=NaN Present_In=Unassigned IN=Unassigned Script=Unknown SC=Zzzz Script=Zzzz Sentence_Break=Other SB=XX
       Sentence_Break=XX Word_Break=Other WB=XX Word_Break=XX
U+0B82 ‹◌ஂ› \N{TAMIL SIGN ANUSVARA}
    \w \pM \p{Mn}
    All Any Alnum Alpha Alphabetic Assigned InTamil Tamil Is_Tamil Case_Ignorable CI M Mn Gr_Ext Grapheme_Extend Graph GrExt ID_Continue IDC
       Mark Nonspacing_Mark Print Taml Word XID_Continue XIDC X_POSIX_Alnum X_POSIX_Alpha X_POSIX_Graph X_POSIX_Print X_POSIX_Word
    Age=1.1 Bidi_Class=Nonspacing_Mark BC=NSM Bidi_Class=NSM Block=Tamil Canonical_Combining_Class=0 Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered
       CCC=NR Canonical_Combining_Class=NR Decomposition_Type=None DT=None East_Asian_Width=Neutral Grapheme_Cluster_Break=EX
       Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Extend GCB=EX Hangul_Syllable_Type=NA Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable HST=NA Joining_Group=No_Joining_Group
       JG=NoJoiningGroup Joining_Type=T Joining_Type=Transparent JT=T Line_Break=CM Line_Break=Combining_Mark LB=CM Numeric_Type=None NT=None
       Numeric_Value=NaN NV=NaN Present_In=1.1 IN=1.1 Present_In=2.0 IN=2.0 Present_In=2.1 IN=2.1 Present_In=3.0 IN=3.0 Present_In=3.1 IN=3.1
       Present_In=3.2 IN=3.2 Present_In=4.0 IN=4.0 Present_In=4.1 IN=4.1 Present_In=5.0 IN=5.0 Present_In=5.1 IN=5.1 Present_In=5.2 IN=5.2
       Present_In=6.0 IN=6.0 Script=Tamil SC=Taml Script=Taml Sentence_Break=EX Sentence_Break=Extend SB=EX Word_Break=Extend WB=Extend
U+0B83 ‹ஃ› \N{TAMIL SIGN VISARGA}
    \w \pL \p{L_} \p{Lo}
    All Any Alnum Alpha Alphabetic Assigned InTamil Tamil Is_Tamil L Lo Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase ID_Continue IDC ID_Start IDS Letter
       L_ Other_Letter Print Taml Word XID_Continue XIDC XID_Start XIDS X_POSIX_Alnum X_POSIX_Alpha X_POSIX_Graph X_POSIX_Print X_POSIX_Word
    Age=1.1 Bidi_Class=L Bidi_Class=Left_To_Right BC=L Block=Tamil Canonical_Combining_Class=0 Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered CCC=NR
       Canonical_Combining_Class=NR Decomposition_Type=None DT=None East_Asian_Width=Neutral Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Other GCB=XX
       Grapheme_Cluster_Break=XX Hangul_Syllable_Type=NA Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable HST=NA Joining_Group=No_Joining_Group
       JG=NoJoiningGroup Joining_Type=Non_Joining JT=U Joining_Type=U Line_Break=AL Line_Break=Alphabetic LB=AL Numeric_Type=None NT=None
       Numeric_Value=NaN NV=NaN Present_In=1.1 IN=1.1 Present_In=2.0 IN=2.0 Present_In=2.1 IN=2.1 Present_In=3.0 IN=3.0 Present_In=3.1 IN=3.1
       Present_In=3.2 IN=3.2 Present_In=4.0 IN=4.0 Present_In=4.1 IN=4.1 Present_In=5.0 IN=5.0 Present_In=5.1 IN=5.1 Present_In=5.2 IN=5.2
       Present_In=6.0 IN=6.0 Script=Tamil SC=Taml Script=Taml Sentence_Break=LE Sentence_Break=OLetter SB=LE Word_Break=ALetter WB=LE
       Word_Break=LE
U+0B84 ‹U+0B84› \N{U+0B84}
    \pC \p{Cn}
    All Any InTamil C Other Cn Unassigned Zzzz Unknown
    Age=Unassigned Bidi_Class=L Bidi_Class=Left_To_Right BC=L Block=Tamil Canonical_Combining_Class=0 Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered
       CCC=NR Canonical_Combining_Class=NR Decomposition_Type=None DT=None East_Asian_Width=Neutral Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Other GCB=XX
       Grapheme_Cluster_Break=XX Hangul_Syllable_Type=NA Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable HST=NA Joining_Group=No_Joining_Group
       JG=NoJoiningGroup Joining_Type=Non_Joining JT=U Joining_Type=U Line_Break=Unknown LB=XX Line_Break=XX Numeric_Type=None NT=None
       Numeric_Value=NaN NV=NaN Present_In=Unassigned IN=Unassigned Script=Unknown SC=Zzzz Script=Zzzz Sentence_Break=Other SB=XX
       Sentence_Break=XX Word_Break=Other WB=XX Word_Break=XX
U+0B85 ‹அ› \N{TAMIL LETTER A}
    \w \pL \p{L_} \p{Lo}
    All Any Alnum Alpha Alphabetic Assigned InTamil Tamil Is_Tamil L Lo Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase ID_Continue IDC ID_Start IDS Letter
       L_ Other_Letter Print Taml Word XID_Continue XIDC XID_Start XIDS X_POSIX_Alnum X_POSIX_Alpha X_POSIX_Graph X_POSIX_Print X_POSIX_Word
    Age=1.1 Bidi_Class=L Bidi_Class=Left_To_Right BC=L Block=Tamil Canonical_Combining_Class=0 Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered CCC=NR
       Canonical_Combining_Class=NR Decomposition_Type=None DT=None East_Asian_Width=Neutral Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Other GCB=XX
       Grapheme_Cluster_Break=XX Hangul_Syllable_Type=NA Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable HST=NA Joining_Group=No_Joining_Group
       JG=NoJoiningGroup Joining_Type=Non_Joining JT=U Joining_Type=U Line_Break=AL Line_Break=Alphabetic LB=AL Numeric_Type=None NT=None
       Numeric_Value=NaN NV=NaN Present_In=1.1 IN=1.1 Present_In=2.0 IN=2.0 Present_In=2.1 IN=2.1 Present_In=3.0 IN=3.0 Present_In=3.1 IN=3.1
       Present_In=3.2 IN=3.2 Present_In=4.0 IN=4.0 Present_In=4.1 IN=4.1 Present_In=5.0 IN=5.0 Present_In=5.1 IN=5.1 Present_In=5.2 IN=5.2
       Present_In=6.0 IN=6.0 Script=Tamil SC=Taml Script=Taml Sentence_Break=LE Sentence_Break=OLetter SB=LE Word_Break=ALetter WB=LE
       Word_Break=LE
```

If you look at other allocated blocks, you see the same sort of thing. It doesn’t make sense to slice up blocks into unrelated things.

As I said, it’s not as though they’re going to run out of space, so I don’t know what the concern is here.

BTW, you can get Unicode exploration and  proceesing tools like [*unichars*](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars),  [*uniprops*](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniprops),  [*uninames*](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uninames) from my [Unicode Command-Line Toolchest](http://training.perl.com/scripts/), either individually from there or the entire suite available through the [CPAN `Unicode::Tussle` suite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode%3a%3aTussle).